# How to best translate "I got A's in 3 of my classes"

Tags: translation

what is some natural ways to say "I got A's in three of my classes" in mandarin? Thank you!

Comment: Can you propose some of your own translations?

Comment: I assume the As are not for classes in mandarin lessons?

Comment: 我有三门课得了A    

Comment: A -> 优秀，B -> 良/良好，C-> 中等，D->及格， F -> 不及格

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me, I told my friend:

> 我有三门课得了A。

Or you can also say

> 我得了三门课的A。

Answer (score 0):

- 我得了"A"在那三門課程, or 在那三門課程中我都得了"A". (You get A from the specific classes out of many)
- 在三門課程中我都得了"A". (You get A from all classes you are attending).

Answer (score 0):

You can say:
我三門課都得了A（I got A in three of my classes ）the use of 都 here it simply tells that the fact that you got A is common for the three classes.

Answer (score -1):

(Assume A is the top score)

I got A's in three of my classes.
我取得了三个班当中的最高分。

(You are good, I never got an A!!)